# Alternative to using @XmlElementWrapper on external Jar/class

Tags: java, jaxb

**TL;DR**

How can I "fake" using the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation for a class in an external jar?

**More Details**

The full scenario is a little convoluted, and there is a lot of legacy code I don't want to have to update, so bear with me... in my project, we are given a jar file from another team. They cannot add the `@XmlElementWrapper` for me because this code is auto generated and has no annotations at all. Inside this code, there are many classes that have typed arrays to other classes.

My problem occurs when trying to marshal/unmarshal these classes. If the typed arrays inside a class are empty, then the XML won't contain a node for that attribute.

For example, if the external class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private OtherClass[] myArray;
    // Getter & Setter also
}
```

the XML generated would look like this:

```
<MyClass>
  <OtherClass>...</OtherClass>
  <OtherClass>...</OtherClass>
  <OtherClass>...</OtherClass>
  <!-- More attributes here... -->
</MyClass>
```

All well and good when there are elements in `OtherClass[] myArray`. The trouble (and `NullPointerExceptions`) occur when `OtherClass[] myArray` is empty. In that case, my XML would look like:

```
<MyClass>
  <!-- More attributes here... -->
</MyClass>
```

So when the XML is unmarshalled, the `OtherClass[] myArray` is `null` and I get a nice StackTrace to look at.

In an ideal world, I would add `@XmlElementWrapper` to the definition of `OtherClass[] myArray`, but as I said, this is an external class, and cannot be edited in this way.

Is there a way around this? I have searched for a way with JAXB Bindings, but so far my searches have yielded no results.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated (even if the answer is "it can't be done").

Comment: Might going back to an XML schema instead of annotations be feasible? Personally I'd rather do anything else: creating new jars using bytecode manipulation to add annotations should be simpler. With special cases etcetera.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Eventually, I caved and just added a load of ``if (xxx != null) {...}`` in a few places. Best I could do under the circumstances (budget constraints...).